# Operator for comparing an n-tuple

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Suppose you have to compare the following two finite ordered list of elements (tuples): $(\psi_{i}, R_{i}, A_{i}, \eta_{i})$ and $(\psi_{i}^{*}, R_{i}, A_{i}, \eta_{i})$ and for instance it turns out that $(\psi_{i}, R_{i}, A_{i}, \eta_{i})$ is at least as good as $(\psi_{i}^{*}, R_{i}, A_{i}, \eta_{i})$ if some conditions hold. Can "at least as good" be represented with the following symbol $\geq$ or there is another way to represent this relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a partial order on the lists.  You could use $\ge$ to show that, but people may confuse it with the usual greater than order.  You might want to use $\succ$ or $\succeq$, which are often used with some other order relation.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. My mistake, I should have used these symbols for ranks you have suggested.